# newcommand for use \oldstylenums of another font

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

How I can define a new command to use the old-style numbers of the package `gfsartemisia` within the default font in pdflatex ?

I tried something like:

```
\newcommand{\oldnum}[1]{{\fontfamily{artemisia}\oldstylenums{#1} \selectfont}}
```

in the preamble to use

```
Some text with default font \oldnum{123} more text with default font
```

but doesn't  work.

Answer (score 7):

The GFS Artemisia fonts have old style numbers in `\scshape`, so the solution should be

```
\newcommand{\oldnum}[1]{{\fontfamily{artemisia}\scshape #1}}
```

Each font choosing declaration has an implicit `\selectfont`.

In any case, `\selectfont` should go *before* the text that we want to be affected by the font selection. Notice also that `\oldstylenums` is an instruction that tells LaTeX to get the digits from a math font, so it doesn't obey `\fontfamily` settings.