# Trouble using \oldstylenums with decimal points and hyphens

Tags: fonts, pdftex, oldstylenums

I am using Computer Modern font (default) with `\oldstylenums` command to typeset numbers in oldstyle format. However I am having trouble using it with non-numeric characters such as decimal points and hyphens.

For e.g. decimal points appear as triangles:

```
Master of Science, Computer Science, \oldstylenums{3.76/4.0}
```

appears as:

[image]

Also, I have trouble with hyphens, etc.

Please suggest remedies.

Comment: I have to point out that it's really easy to get oldstyle numbers with fontspec, meaning with XeTeX and LuaTeX and OpenType fonts (like `lmodern`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

redefines `\oldstylenums`to use the 8-bit encoding TS1 instead of the 7-bit math encoding `OML`.

### Extended support

The following example parses the string to replace the digits by the old style variants.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\oldstyle}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \toks@={}%
  \@oldstyle#1\scrollmode
}
\newcommand*{\@oldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace\scrollmode{%
    \expandafter\endgroup\the\expandafter\toks@\@gobble
  }{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace\@sptoken{%
    \expandafter
    \@oldstyleadd\expandafter\space\expandafter\@empty
    \romannumeral-`\x
  }{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace0{\@oldstyleadd\textzerooldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace1{\@oldstyleadd\textoneoldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace2{\@oldstyleadd\texttwooldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace3{\@oldstyleadd\textthreeoldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace4{\@oldstyleadd\textfouroldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace5{\@oldstyleadd\textfiveoldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace6{\@oldstyleadd\textsixoldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace7{\@oldstyleadd\textsevenoldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace8{\@oldstyleadd\texteightoldstyle}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace9{\@oldstyleadd\textnineoldstyle}{%
    \@@oldstyle
  }}}}}}}}}}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@oldstyleadd}[2]{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@#1}%
  \@oldstyle
}
  \newcommand*{\@@oldstyle}[1]{%
  \@oldstyleadd{#1}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Master of Science, Computer Science, \oldstyle{0-1--2---3; 7, 3.76/4.0}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Good things, when short, are twice as good :)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks for the suggestion, it solves the decimal point problem, but hyphen is now converted to `=` symbol.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni, but on the contrary, `=` is converted to a long hyphen in this way.

Comment: @Fran: Thanks. How can I get the short hyphen?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni, I do not know with a single key, but please see the trick of `\sout` in my answer. It works also with `textcomp`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want old style figures throughout your document, you have a couple of choices assuming you still want to use the Computer Modern fonts or variations thereof.

### Package `eco`

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eco}
```

### Package `cfr-lm`

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstyle=true]{cfr-lm}
```

The second package uses the Latin Modern fonts, which are very similar to Computer Modern; the first one uses a set of virtual fonts based on European Modern, again a variation of Computer Modern. I'd favor the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the best practice would be to leave out characters other than digits.

However, I could be a little messy, but you can obtain decimal points (mid point or down point), hyphens and fractions inside `\oldstylenums` in this way:

```
\usepackage{ulem} % needed for \sout{}
 ...
\oldstylenums{3·76=4·0 \sout{~} 3:76=4:0}
```

Another less tangled solution could be to define a [newcommand for use \oldstylenums of another font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43929/newcommand-for-use-oldstylenums-of-another-font) that allow the use of normal characters inside the command:

```
\newcommand{\oldnum}[1]{{\fontfamily{artemisia}\scshape #1}}

\oldnum{3·76/4·0 - 3.76/4.0}
```

Note that in this case in there are text inside \oldnum, it appear as small caps instead of italics.

[image: MWE]