# What is the correct way of writing a percentage next to \oldstylenums?

Tags: oldstylenums

If I want to write in text e.g. 1.1-1.5% and use `\oldstylenums` to get non-lining numbers, what would be the correct way of specifying the percent sign?

When I simply write the percent sign as

```
\oldstylenums{1.1}--\oldstylenums{1.5}\%
```

the percent sign seems too large and out-of-place next to non-lining numbers and lowercase letters. Is there some way of getting a smaller, "lowercase" percent sign or should the "capitalized" percent sign simply be considered correct?

Comment: `\oldstylenums{1.1}` prints "incorrectly": only digits should be in the argument.

Comment: Didn't old books put the % in a superscript? Similar to how they did decimals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd never use oldstyle digits in these cases. Moreover, their input with the standard fonts is very cumbersome:

```
\oldstylenums{1}.\oldstylenums{1}--\oldstylenum{1}.\oldstylenum{5}\%
```

is something I'd never stand (note that a period in the argument of `\oldstylenum` produces a funny symbol).

You could use fonts that *have* oldstyle digits to begin with, for instance the Latin Modern fonts as modified by Clea F. Reese:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  rm={oldstyle=true,tabular=true},
  sf={oldstyle=false,tabular=true},
  tt={oldstyle=false,tabular=true}
]{cfr-lm}

\newcommand{\smallpercent}{{\footnotesize\%}}

\begin{document}
1.1--1.2\smallpercent\quad 1.1--1.3\smallpercent

1.1--1.4\smallpercent\quad 1.1--1.5\smallpercent

1.1--1.6\smallpercent\quad 1.1--1.7\smallpercent

1.1--1.8\smallpercent\quad 1.1--1.9\smallpercent

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\small` doesn't seem right; but the overall appearance is a clear invitation not to use oldstyle figures for this purpose.

Instead of the package `cfr-lm` you can use `eco`:

```
\usepackage{eco}
```

Both allow for changing the style of digits mid document; `cfr-lm` is more powerful, `eco` has only `\newstylenums`.

Comment: Great, thanks! You can get rid of the weird decimals as explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75633/trouble-using-oldstylenums-with-decimal-points-and-hyphens) and I shorten the command using \newcommand, but I agree - there should be no such interventions in the content itself. Ideally the document template would detect that automatically (e.g. place new style numerals in tables and old style in text).